# Plotting OpenStreetMap with ggmap

Tags: r, ggplot2, openstreetmap, ggmap

I'm trying to get districts of Warsaw and draw them on google map. Using this code, where 2536107 is relation code for OpenStreetMap single Warsaw district, gives me almost what I want but with a few bugs. There is general outline but also lines between points which shouldn't be connected. What am I doing wrong?

```
map <- get_googlemap('warsaw', zoom =10) 
warszawa <- get_osm(relation(2536107), full = T)
warszawa.sp <- as_sp(warszawa, what='lines')
warsawfort <- fortify(warszawa.sp)

mapa_polski <- ggmap(map, extent='device', legend="bottomleft") 
warsawfort2 <- geom_polygon(aes(x = long, y = lat), 
               data = warsawfort, fill="blue", colour="black", 
               alpha=0.0, size = 0.3)

base <- mapa_polski + warsawfort2 
base
```

Edit: I figured it must be somehow connected with order of plotting every point/line but I have no idea how to fix this.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is a way to generate your map without using external packages: don't use `osmar`...

[This link](https://s3.amazonaws.com/metro-extracts.mapzen.com/warsaw.imposm-shapefiles.zip), to the excellent Mapzen website, provides a set of shapefiles of administrative areas in Poland. If you download and unzip it, you will see a shapfile set called `warsaw.osm-admin.*`. This is a *polygon* shapefile of all the districts in Poland, conveniantly indexed by osm_id(!!). The code below assumes you have downloaded the file and unzipped it into the "directory with your shapefiles".

```
library(ggmap)
library(ggplot2)
library(rgdal)

setwd(" <directory with your shapefiles> ")
pol    <- readOGR(dsn=".",layer="warsaw.osm-admin")
spp    <- pol[pol$osm_id==-2536107,]
wgs.84 <- "+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84"
spp    <- spTransform(spp,CRS(wgs.84))

map    <- get_googlemap('warsaw', zoom =10) 
spp.df <- fortify(spp)

ggmap(map, extent='device', legend="bottomleft") +
  geom_polygon(data = spp.df, aes(x = long, y=lat, group=group), 
               fill="blue", alpha=0.2) +
  geom_path(data=spp.df, aes(x=long, y=lat, group=group), 
            color="gray50", size=0.3)
```

[image]

Two nuances: (1) The osm IDs are stored as negative numbers, so you have to use, e.g.,

```
spp    <- pol[pol$osm_id==-2536107,]
```

to extract the relevant district, and (2) the shapefile  is not projected in WGS84 (long/lat). So we have to reproject it using:

```
spp    <- spTransform(spp,CRS(wgs.84))
```

The reason `osmar` doesn't work is that the paths are in the wrong order. Your `warszawa.sp` is a `SpatialLinesDataframe`, made up of a set of paths (12 in your case), each of which is made up of a set of line segments. When you use `fortify(...)` on this, `ggplot` tries to combine them into a single sequence of points. But since the paths are not in convex order, ggplot tries, for example, to connect a path that ends in the northeast, to a path the begins in the southwest. This is why you're getting all the extra lines. You can see this by coloring the segments:

```
xx=coordinates(warszawa.sp)
colors=rainbow(11)
plot(t(bbox(warszawa.sp)))
lapply(1:11,function(i)lines(xx[[i]][[1]],col=colors[i],lwd=2))
```

[image]

The colors are in "rainbow" order (red, orange, yellow, green, etc.). Clearly, the lines are not in that order.

**EDIT** Response to @ako's comment.

There is a way to "fix" the SpatialLines object, but it's not trivial. The function `gPolygonize(...)` in the `rgeos` package will take a list of `SpatialLines` and convert to a `SpatialPolygons` object, which can be used in ggplot with `fortify(...)`. One huge problem (which I don't understand, frankly), is that OP's `warszaw.sp` object has 12 lines, two of which seem to be duplicates - this causes `gPolygonize(...)` to fail. So if you create a SpatialLines list with just the first 11 paths, you can convert `warszawa.sp` to a polygon. This is not general however, as I can't predict how or if it would work with other `SpatialLines` objects converted from `osm`. Here's the code, which leads to the same map as above.

```
library(rgeos)
coords <- coordinates(warszawa.sp)
sll <- lapply(coords[1:11],function(x) SpatialLines(list(Lines(list(Line(x[[1]])),ID=1))))
spp <- gPolygonize(sll)
spp.df <- fortify(spp)
ggmap(map, extent='device', legend="bottomleft") +
  geom_polygon(data = spp.df, aes(x = long, y=lat, group=group), 
               fill="blue", alpha=0.2) +
  geom_path(data=spp.df, aes(x=long, y=lat, group=group), 
            color="gray50", size=0.3)
```

Comment: +1 for explaining the error so clearly. If the alternative file had not been available, is there a trivial way using topology to reorder by adjacency, that is; fixing rather than replacing?

Comment: Man, ur golden ! I actually realised that it consists of lines plotted in the wrong order but it never came to my mind that somewhere there is solution simple as that - shape file of Warsaw (thought it'd be too good to be true for such particular data set) - now all I need to do is import warsaw.osm-admin.shp and it's all taken care of ! Great thanks for you man !

Comment: @ako  Yes, there is but it's not trivial. See my edits at the end.

Comment: @jlhoward, were the duplicates perfect or approximate?

Comment: @ako I don't know. `coordinates(warszawa.sp)` is a list of lists of the coordinates. You can compare by inspection, I guess.

Comment: @jlhoward I just found this post since I was looking for posts related to the osmar `packackge`. I was looking for a shapefile for roads in Australia. But, OSM does not have shape files. But they have osm files. So I was thinking about converting osm to sp to data frame. But, I had the impression that osmar may not be a good option seeing your post here. Is there any particular downside of the package? If you have experiences using the package, would be be possible for you to share your experience?

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure this is a general hangup--I can reproduce your example and see the issue. My first thought was that you didn't supply group=id which are typically used for polygons with many lines, but you have lines, so that should not be needed.

The only way I could get it to display properly was by changing your lines into a polygon off script. `Qgis' line to polygon` didn't get this "right", getting a large donut hole, so I used `ArcMap`, which produced a full polygon. If this is a one off that may work for your workflow. Odds are it is not. In that case, perhaps RGDAL can transform lines to polygons, assuming that is indeed a general problem.

Upon reading the polygon shapefile and fortifying that, your code ran without problems.
[image]